# Using vim as text editor for IPython (Mac OSX)

Tags: macos, vim, ipython

I'm trying to get vim-ipython working, and have been using this reference guide (https://github.com/ivanov/vim-ipython).

---

First, I created the following directory:

```
/Users/***/.vim/ftconfig/python/ipy.vim
```

However, when I type `%edit` in IPython, I still get

```
No default editor available.
Specify a GUI text editor in the `IPythonWidget.editor` configurable to enable the %edit magic
```

---

Then, I tried typing the following in IPython:

```
source ipy.vim
```

I got an error:

```
File "<ipython-input-7-505e44392e8d>", line 1
    source ipy.vim
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

Finally, I edited `ipython_qtconsole.config.py` to include the following line:

```
c.IPythonWidget.editor = "/Users/***/.vim/ftplugin/python/ipy.vim"
```

Still no dice.  I can get emacs to work by editing c.IpythonWidge.editor, but I'm not sure how to change it to use vim as the editor.

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure you're supposed to type `:source ipy.vim` from inside Vim, not IPython. Also, the `editor` parameter presumably needs to point at the Vim executable itself, not the `ipy.vim` file.

Comment: Yup.  You are right.  I am an idiot.

Comment: Where can I find the vim executable? Googling is only leading me to the vim config files et. al